# Invalid Packages on Older VueJS Project

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm trying to install vuejs project. It's created on 2019.

When I use `npm install` it returns so many errors and warnings.

It begins with:

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
```

And returns

```
"Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):"
```

When try to work project.

I tried `npm list --depth=3`

```
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: eslint@7.15.0 
npm ERR! invalid: graphql@15.4.0 
npm ERR! missing: typescript@>=2.7, required by ts-node@8.10.2
npm ERR! invalid: ts-node@8.10.2
```

Whats wrong with that,
I tried to install those packages as specific. But both of them are returning error. And when I try to update them, vuetify returns error, too.

How can I work this project?

Comment: If your versions are not so important remove node_modules folder and run npm install

Comment: And what is the error? You can try creating a file named `.npmrc`inside your project and putting `legacy-peer-deps=true` inside this file.

Comment: The version of NPM is not the same, like npm v4 vs npm v7. Either delete the lock file and re-create a new one or use the older one. This is not related to the modules themselves.